# Can't @InjectMocks attribute call Mockito's method thenReturn?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I started using `Mockito` this week and I'm having a problem to understand `@InjectMocks` field.

I have a class A that is like this:

```
public class A {

    public B b;

    public C c;

    public String string;

}
```

when I use it at `JUnit` test with `Mockito`, I call it like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test {

    @Mock
    B b;

    @Mock
    C c;

    @InjectMocks
    A a;

    ...

}
```

but I want to set the **string** attribute! I try it like this:

```
Mockito.when(a.getString()).thenReturn("STRING");
```

however, the test throws an Exception:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
>   when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
>   For example:
>       when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
>
> Also, this error might show up because:
>   1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.    Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
>   2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
>   3. the parent of the mocked class is not public.    It is a limitation of the mock engine.

Can I do something else to set this field?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Can I do something else to set this field?

Yes you can annotate your field with `@Spy` too as next:

```
@Spy
@InjectMocks
A a;
```

Then you will be able to do `Mockito.when(a.getString()).thenReturn("STRING");`

Indeed when it is annotated with `@InjectMocks` only ,`Mockito` doesn't mock it, it creates a normal instance of the class `A` by default, such that you cannot use `Mockito.when()` on it. As workaround, you can ask `Mockito` to partially mock it using `@Spy`.

**The exception that you actually get is due to the case #2 provided in the error message:**

> inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

Comment: Awesome! I wasn't understanding why I can't do it with this "answer" of Mockito's Exception. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: While this may work, it is a gross misuse of the API. What the OP really wanted was to create a non-mock instance of `A` with the "string" also set to some value. Injecting such non-mock values is a feature that Mockito doesn't currently have (I think), but it can have and it was already requested in the past.